Limiting current vs Steady-state limiting current
I have been reading on the concept of limiting current.
In books, the mass-transfer limiting current is given by,
$$ i_L = \frac{nFADC^*}{\delta}$$
Often the Cottrell equation is introduced.
However, later on there is the introduction of a
'steady-state' limiting current at long time scales, given by:
$$ i_{ss} = \gamma nFDC^*r_0$$
What is the difference (if any) between these two 'limiting' currents, can they be considered the same under certain conditions?
An example of a book where this is discussed is "Handbook of Electrochemistry" by C. Zoski, also seen it in "Electrochemical Methods" by Bard and Faulkner.

The steady-state limiting current is especially important for microelectrodes, because the diffusion mode is not semi-linear, but radial.

Short answer: yes, they are the same.
The general equation for the limiting current is usually written this way : $i_{l} = nFAmC^* $, with m the mass tranfer coefficient. This is the maximum current measurable at the electrode because of mass transfer.
The steady state current is the (limiting) current you can actually measure at an electrode after a potential step under mass transfer limitations. This is usually measured for small electrodes, it takes too long to establish for macro electrodes and you would have convection mixing in. The exact form depends on the geometry (the $\gamma$ term in your equation).
I think that people use the name limiting current in general and when talking about rotating disk electrodes (RDE) and steady state current when dealing with (ultra)microelectrodes in potential step experiments ("steady state voltammetry" as it is called in the Bard and Faulkner).

Thank you very much for your insight. There is a study that has chronoamperometry data (I vs time) curves for a period of 2 hours. The working electrode has a diameter of 1.75mm so I do not think it classifies as an UME, but the chronoamperometry curves does reach a constant value as time grows large. Would it be correct to interpret that as the steaty-state limiting current?

I think so. Check the chronoamperometry chapter in Bard and Faulkner. I think it is developped there.
